# Finding help files for moduled package functions in R

Tags: r, module, package, roxygen2

I am writing an R package which is organized into modules as per Sebastian [Warnholz's modules package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modules/). Each function is organized into its own R file under, e.g., `R/m1/fun.R`. Each one of those files begins with roxygen code. The modules are defined in another file, `R/modules.R`. Here's an idea of how that file is structured:

```
#' Module 1
#' @name m1
#' @export
m1 <- modules::module({
    expose("R/m1/fun.R")
    expose("R/m1/foo.R")
})
```

The package checks and builds cleanly and I can call functions by issuing `m1$fun()` and `m1$foo()`. However, calling the help files don't work, no matter what I try (i.e., combinations of `?` or `help()` with the function names, with or without the module prefix `m1$`.

Actually, I can't even expect the help files to be there, because after running `devtools::document()`, the roxygen code is not converted into `man/*.Rd` files. So I guess my problem is having `devtools::document()` search into the `R` subfolders. Running `devtools::document("R/m1")` doesn't do the trick, though.

One thing that works is putting the function scripts in the parent folder, `R/`, but then they lose the module scope and the help files (but not the functions themselves) can be seen at package level. Moreover, the "usage" section will state "foo(...)" instead of "m1$foo(...)", which sounds inadequate but I am not sure is currently fixable. This is my first time working with modules, so I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of organizing my functions and help files.

Comment: Currently packages like devtools will not recognize or support subfolders in `./R`. I cannot recommend a workflow with subfolders inside R packages because you will have to 'work against' all available tools. Documentation of modules can be done using a single man-page including a description of each public function. You can also think about writing a function returning a module. Then the static code analysis tools of R CMD check will work and can help. You can then still use `expose` referring to non-exported modules inside the package to compose the public interface.

Comment: Please consider to open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wahani/modules) if you'd like to discuss the role of modules inside packages.